# how to use parent or sibling in css selenium when there is only class i.e only one attribute available and both child elements have same class name

Tags: css, css-selectors, selenium-ide

here is the console

[image: click on this]

i have got answer using xpath but want to learn in css.

i have written xpath solution for it but kindly help with css.

[image: xpath solution(click)]

Comment: Are you looking for :nth-child in CSS?

Comment: Yes. the parent element has 2 child elements with same class value in <div> tag as you can see in the image, i wanted to know how do we write css selector instead of xpath and select the first child.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child - and be aware that the numbering starts from 1 unlike, say, javascript arrays which start from 0.

Comment: i tried this in console for above issue i put up --->  $$("div[class='.footer__info-links.grid-col.grid-col-2']>div:nth-child(1)") .                                                                    
it didnt work for some reason